# Find UIView in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Let me first say, I am beginner with iOS programming and dealing with one of the older project. As per my question title, I was searching, at which place in Storyboard my UIView exist that defined in header file?

Here is overview:

[image]

There are so many screen present in Storyboard so I become confused where I have attached my UIView in Storyboard component. In actual application it appeared but within Storyboard I can't find any particular view created.

Does a short cut exist to find the relation between header file to Storyboard that I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the gray circle on the left section where `IBOutlet`s are written.

[image]

Tap on 'storyboard name - view name', it'll show that view on storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your side reply - for me it happened something different but overall you have represent correctly so I am making this as correct. I have xib file exist in project that manages all sub views - at their I can able to find app UIViews.

Answer (score 0):

First you go to your storyboard and after click below squrebox near by "View as iPhone SE" and you showing side pane with all viewController and after press command: ⌘+f with your view you can get easy your view.

Comment: Basically if you check into above screenshots then empty circles exist with IBOutlet - do you think UIView get generated at rung time? Because within Storyboard, I can't able to find this.